# Improper sizing on load

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a plugin called [SlabText][1]. It's great and works across multiple browsers, however, I ran into an issue with proper sizing. When the text loads initially it is not utilizing the space allocated to it. If I refresh or re-size the page, it suddenly scales properly.

First I thought it was due to other plugin kicking off around the same time, so I've added delay for this one, but I still have the same issue. Seems I've tried all sorts of things -- just not sure what the cause is.

Not sure if there's any value in this, most of the re-sizing is done withing the plugin, but here's how I put it all together.

```
$(".banner").unslider({
        speed: 1500,              //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
        delay: 25000,             //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
        complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
        keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcut
        dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
        fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
    });


    var stS = "<span class=\'slabtext\'>",
        stE = "</span>"
        prc = "<div class=\"mar20top alnRt\"><a class=\"btn\" href=\"/pricing\"><span class=\"uico ui-icon-tag icoSpan\"></span>Pricing</a> &nbsp; ",

        txt_CS = [
            "improve information architecture (IA) with",
            "CARD SORTING",
            "Try our online (remote) tool",
            "get instant results with built-in data analytics",
            "unlimited tests & participants / open, closed or hybrid test / images, text or mixed Cards"
        ],
        lnk = prc + "<a class=\"btn\" href=\"/features/Card_Sorting\"><span class=\"uico ui-icon-star icoSpan\"></span>Features</a> &nbsp; <a class=\"btn\" href=\"/CardSorting\"><span class=\"uico ui-icon-newwin icoSpan\"></span>Learn more about Card Sorting</a></div>";

    $("#CardSort_HDR").html(stS + txt_CS.join(stE + stS) + stE).slabText();
    $("#CardSort_HDR span:nth-child(2)").css({"color":"#b9cde5", "line-height":"0.8"});
    $("#CardSort_HDR span:nth-child(3), #CardSort_HDR span:nth-child(5)").css({"color":"#999", "line-height":"0.8"});
    $("#promo li:nth-child(1)").append(lnk).hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(2200);
```

HTML

```
<div id="contArea" class="banner">
<ul id="promo">
    <li class="h1" id="CardSort_HDR"></li>
    <li class="h1" id="PrMatrix_HDR"></li>
    <li class="h1" id="heurEval_HDR"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you recently change something?  It works for me on page load.

Comment: In Firefox 22.0, it seems to work fine.  In Chrome 28.0.1500.72 it never fills the space (regardless of refreshes) until I resize the window; same with IE10.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the code that is used to perform the reizing? I'm having a similar issue calculating a height, and only Chrome and Opera 15 fail in doing it properly unless the window is resized, because they return invalid heights (for me they include the height of one toolbar).

Comment: You don't have to escape single quotes inside double ones: `var stS = "<span class=\'slabtext\'>",`

Comment: Why are you building the mark-up with script? Put the HTML where it belongs and just manipulate it as necessary.

Comment: @danwellman Are you talking about he actual words? This is the format required by the plugin in order to preserve line breaks, where I need them.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using another plugin. You know, with the whole separation of content, presentation and behaviour thing and all.